# How to "allocate" enough vertical space above the baseline in a <p> element to support <sup> elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a series of "blocks" on the screen that are consistently placed, but I'm having trouble when one of them has `<sup>&reg;</sup>` in it, and that makes it take up more vertical space:

[image]

Each block looks like this in code (see example #2 for runnable code snippet):

```
<div class="myblock">
  <div class="bin">
    <span class="glue"></span>
    <p class="bingo">Text goes here</p>
    <span class="glue"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

- The dashed rectangles are the `p.bingo` element that contains the desired text.
- Each `div.bin` element is a horizontal container using `flex` to add equal space around the `p.bingo` element.
- Each `div.myblock` element is an overall container that adds vertical padding and constrains the overall width

**In each of the `p.bingo` elements, I want to add enough room between the text baseline and the top of the element so that the vertical space is consistent. How would I do this?**

I tried adding `min-height`, and it fixes the difference in the block heights, but then the baseline positions aren't consistent. (See example #2)

[image]

Example #1.

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
}
div.myline {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.myblock {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #aaff88;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
div.bin {
  display: flex;
}
span.glue {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 0;
}
p.bingo {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
div.show-baseline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 2.8ex;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="myline">
  <div class="myblock"><div class="bin">
    <span class="glue"></span>
  <p class="bingo">
    Spiffy hair!
  </p>
    <span class="glue"></span>
  </div></div>
</div>
<div class="myline">
  <div class="myblock"><div class="bin">
    <span class="glue"></span>
  <p class="bingo">
    Spiffy<sup>&reg;</sup> hair!
  </p>
    <span class="glue"></span>
    </div></div>
</div>
<div class="myline">
  <div class="myblock"><div class="bin">
    <span class="glue"></span>
    <p class="bingo">
      Vacuum grease
    </p>
    <span class="glue"></span>
    </div></div>
</div>
  <div class="show-baseline"></div>
</div>
```

Example #2:

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
}
div.myline {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.myblock {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #aaff88;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
div.bin {
  display: flex;
}
span.glue {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 0;
}
p.bingo {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  min-height: 3.2ex;
}
div.show-baseline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 2.8ex;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="myline">
  <div class="myblock"><div class="bin">
    <span class="glue"></span>
  <p class="bingo">
    Spiffy hair!
  </p>
    <span class="glue"></span>
  </div></div>
</div>
<div class="myline">
  <div class="myblock"><div class="bin">
    <span class="glue"></span>
  <p class="bingo">
    Spiffy<sup>&reg;</sup> hair!
  </p>
    <span class="glue"></span>
    </div></div>
</div>
<div class="myline">
  <div class="myblock"><div class="bin">
    <span class="glue"></span>
    <p class="bingo">
      Vacuum grease
    </p>
    <span class="glue"></span>
    </div></div>
</div>
  <div class="show-baseline"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [a hack](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-superscripts-and-subscripts-from-affecting-line-height/) for ensuring that `<sup>` and `<sub>` don't negatively affect line-height, and aligning them correctly can be achieved with a combination of `vertical-align: baseline` and `position: relative`, and then setting the corresponding `top` offset:

```
sup, sub {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
}

sup {
  top: -0.4em;
}

sub {
  top: 0.4em;
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
}

div.myline {
  display: inline-block;
}

div.myblock {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #aaff88;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

div.bin {
  display: flex;
}

span.glue {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 0;
}

p.bingo {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}

div.show-baseline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 2.8ex;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed green;
}

sup,
sub {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
}

sup {
  top: -0.4em;
}

sub {
  top: 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="myline">
    <div class="myblock">
      <div class="bin">
        <span class="glue"></span>
        <p class="bingo">
          Spiffy hair!
        </p>
        <span class="glue"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myline">
    <div class="myblock">
      <div class="bin">
        <span class="glue"></span>
        <p class="bingo">
          Spiffy<sup>&reg;</sup> hair!
        </p>
        <span class="glue"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myline">
    <div class="myblock">
      <div class="bin">
        <span class="glue"></span>
        <p class="bingo">
          Vacuum grease
        </p>
        <span class="glue"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="show-baseline"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get rid of flexbox then you can consider both pseudo element and you make them aligned at the `sub` and `super` to make sure you will always have the behavior of `<sub>` and `<sup>` on each element. In your case, one pseudo element is enough if you only want to use `<sup>`

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
}
div.myline {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.myblock {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #aaff88;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 text-align:center; /* added this */
}
/* The magic start here*/
p.bingo:before {
  content:"";
  vertical-align:sub;
}
p.bingo:after {
  content:"";
  vertical-align:super;
}
/**/
p.bingo {
  margin: 0;
  display:inline-block; /* added this */
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
div.show-baseline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 2.8ex;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="myline">
  <div class="myblock">
  <p class="bingo">
    Spiffy hair!
  </p></div>
</div>
<div class="myline">
  <div class="myblock">
  <p class="bingo">
    Spiffy<sup>&reg;</sup> hair!
  </p></div>
</div>
<div class="myline">
  <div class="myblock">
    <p class="bingo">
      Vacuum <sub>&reg;</sub>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="show-baseline"></div>
</div>
```